# no resource found for @style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabView

Tags: android, android-styles

I'm trying to customize my ActionBar's tab indicator following [this](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html) reference, however I'm getting the error:

```
 Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabView'.
```

Minimum SDK is set to 14, target SDK = 18. Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

I already have the following styles which work:

```
     <style name="sMain" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:icon">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarDivider">@null</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBar" parent="android:Widget.Holo.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionBarDivider">@null</item>

</style>
```

Comment: oh sorry, forgot to accept. Your suggestion works, thanks

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You should be referencing

```
@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabView
```

Typo in the docs - they left off the `android:`.

Comment: ```@android:style```, no?

Answer (score 1):

This is what you need to do:

Create a Style for your app:
Here I am customizing the Tab Bar and it's text (I am using a base compatibility theme but you can use HOLO or anything you like):

```
   <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="android:actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/TabTextStyle</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/TabBarStyle</item>

        <!-- Support library compatibility (ActionBarCompat) -->
        <item name="actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/TabTextStyle</item>
        <item name="actionBarTabStyle">@style/TabBarStyle</item>
    </style>
```

Create those styles:

```
<style name="TabTextStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.TabText">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/ab_tab_txt</item>
</style>

<style name="TabBarStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.TabView">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/tab_indicator</item>
</style>
```

For the color and drawables, you can create a selector that allows the tab to change based on clicks and selection:

File: res/color/ab_tab_txt (I am using the color file from res/values to set my constants, but you can place the color like so: #FFF)

```
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item android:state_selected="true" android:color="@color/ab_tab_txt_selected"/>
        <item android:color="@color/ab_tab_txt_unselected"/>
    </selector>
```

File res/drawable/tab_indicator

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- Non focused states -->
    <item android:state_focused="false"
        android:state_selected="false"
        android:state_pressed="false"
        android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
    <item android:state_focused="false"
        android:state_selected="true" 
        android:state_pressed="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected_example" />

    <!-- Focused states -->
    <item android:state_focused="true"
        android:state_selected="false"
        android:state_pressed="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/tab_unselected_focused_example" />
    <item android:state_focused="true"
        android:state_selected="true" 
        android:state_pressed="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected_focused_example" />

    <!-- Pressed -->
    <!--    Non focused states -->
    <item android:state_focused="false"
        android:state_selected="false"
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/tab_unselected_pressed_example" />
    <item android:state_focused="false" 
        android:state_selected="true"  
        android:state_pressed="true" 
        android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected_pressed_example" />

    <!--    Focused states -->
    <item android:state_focused="true" 
        android:state_selected="false" 
        android:state_pressed="true" 
        android:drawable="@drawable/tab_unselected_pressed_example" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" 
        android:state_selected="true"  
        android:state_pressed="true" 
        android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected_pressed_example" />
</selector>
```

My drawable files are NinePatches that I create using this useful tool:
http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/

Comment: the problem is that the SDK cannot resolve @style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.TabView  Please check my updatet question

Comment: Well yes, I am using AppCompat for lower API versions.
Unless you really need to use Min SDK 14, you could use ActionBarCompat for any device down to SDK 7.
Anyhow, in your case, this should be useful: http://android-developers.blogspot.se/2011/04/customizing-action-bar.html

Comment: Change it to Widget.Holo.ActionBar

Comment: when I changed that it just took that drawable and stretched it to the whole Tabs area. I only need to replace the blue indicator below the Tabs. Documentation says: Android 3.0 and higher only:                <!-- ActionBar tabs styles -->
    <style name="MyActionBarTabs"
           parent="@style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabView">
        <!-- tab indicator -->
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/actionbar_tab_indicator</item>
    <style>

Comment: You need to check the link I posted before. The way I posted is the official new way you should do it. But, since you require Holo support only, you should do this: (I post it again) http://android-developers.blogspot.se/2011/04/customizing-action-bar.html

Comment: I took a look, thanks. I forgot to mention: I dont have any text, but only icons in my actionBar. And I only need to replace the blue underline indicating the active Tab

Comment: Change "@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.TabView" to "android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBarView_TabView"

Comment: Remove the one regarding Text changes

Comment: android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBarView.TabView cannot be resolved either (no matter if Light or Holo only)

Comment: Then I would strongly recommend moving towards ActionBarCompat, it is included in the new Support Library v7. There is not much documentation regarding styling Holo.